# Get my Brand in the middle of my flexbox top bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a topbar above my navbar so this is not a nav and does not need the hamburger icon on small screens. I want the top bar to have an icon to the left end, a brand in the middle and 2 icons at the right end. I have been trying to use flexbox to achieve my goal but I can not get the central brand to be centered.

[image: top bar not centering]

My code is

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-light topbar">
<div id="compassicon" class="d-flex justify-content-end text-muted">
  <div class="text-muted fa fa-compass fa-2x"></div>
  <div id="townlabel" class="mr-auto p-2">Town</div>
  <div class="center">
  <p class="title-border title-text">Brand Name
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-muted fa fa-user-o fa-2x"></div>
  <div class="text-muted fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title-border {
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 20px;
background: #3BA7A4;


}

.title-text {
color: white !important ;
 /*font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;*/
font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;

}

#townlabel * {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;

}
#compassicon {
display: inline-block;
}

.topbar {
max-height: 41px;
}

.brand-heading {
 float: none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would you want something like this? Then `text-align:center` on the parent element and `display: inline-block` on the text element

```css
.title-border {
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 20px;
background: #3BA7A4;


}

.title-text {
color: white !important ;
 /*font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;*/
font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;

}

#townlabel * {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;

}
#compassicon {
text-align: center;
}

.topbar {
max-height: 41px;
}

.brand-heading {
 float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-light topbar">
<div id="compassicon" class="d-flex justify-content-end text-muted">
  <div class="text-muted fa fa-compass fa-2x"></div>
  <div id="townlabel" class="mr-auto p-2">Town</div>
  <div class="center" style="display: inline-block;">
  <p class="title-border title-text">Brand Name
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-muted fa fa-user-o fa-2x"></div>
  <div class="text-muted fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This made no difference on my setup.

Comment: So, it's not working as shown in the code snippet executor window above?

Comment: No the 'town' doesn't stay left in the snippet executor window above. It is above the Brand name and the icons do not show.